# DRF Validation in serializers or validation in view-functions. How to use validation correctly?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

What is the best way to use validation in DRF? For example:
into serializer class:

```
def validate_username(self, value): # username its field
    if value in self.BAD_USERNAME:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Wrong username')
    return value
```

or without validation in serializer and validate into viewset:

```
serializer.is_valid()
username = serializer.validated_data.get('username')
if username in BAD_USERNAME:
    raise serializers.ValidationError('Wrong username')
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case.

If all of your views or code that uses that serializer would need to perform that specific validation, then it's best to use the `validate_` method.

This should be your approach by default.

If only your one view needs to do that validation, but in other places in your code you'd accept `BAD_USERNAME`, then it's best to put it in your view.